# Mobile Site not having Review Possibility

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

Is it possible, for the mobile site, to have the review possibility in place?

With my Nexus 4 it is much better to cope with the full site than my old Wildfire S, but having a mobile review system would be much better.

Anybody in favour?

Comment: I find it disappointing to see that the answer given (no offence there @phwd) will smother the voting.... I will rephrase the question, to be an open one, the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been brought up on Meta SO before and the answer is, the SE Team isn't really looking into it right now. The status has been deferred.

[Review option on mobile phone not available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148616/review-option-on-mobile-phone-not-available)

> We currently do not have a mobile version of /review. You can visit /review on a mobile device however it will not be optimized for a mobile device. We have a longer term goal of making a mobile version.